# Optimising MySQL query with lots of self-joins

Tags: mysql, optimization

I have an `entity_relationship` table that describes relationships between entities. Each relationship will have 2+ entities involved.

In some cases it can be said that one entity is a *constituent* of a *constituency*. This is stored in the `entity_relationship` table.

I then intend to add entities to the relationships based on this: If entity *Joe Bloggs* is a constituent of constituency *University of Life*, and the *University of Life* is itself a constituent of constituency *Made Up Universities* then I will add Joe Bloggs into the 2nd relationship as an *implied-constituent*.

When all the *implied-consituent* relationships are populated (by running the query until no records are added) I'll have a quick way to find out who's linked to what without needing to do recursion at that stage.

The entity_relationship table looks like:

```
+-----------------+---------------+
| Field           | Type          |
+-----------------+---------------+
| entity_id       | int(10)       |
| relationship_id | int(10)       |
| type            | enum(...)     |
+-----------------+---------------+
```

and has keys (currently LOADS of 'em, trying to optimise!)

```
+------------+----------+--------------+-----------------+-------------+------+
| Non_unique | Key_name | Seq_in_index | Column_name     | Cardinality | Null |
+------------+----------+--------------+-----------------+-------------+------+
|          0 | PRIMARY  |            1 | entity_id       |      179429 |      |
|          0 | PRIMARY  |            2 | relationship_id |      179429 |      |
|          1 | r_t_e    |            1 | relationship_id |      179429 |      |
|          1 | r_t_e    |            2 | type            |      179429 | YES  |
|          1 | r_t_e    |            3 | entity_id       |      179429 |      |
|          1 | t_r_e    |            1 | type            |           8 | YES  |
|          1 | t_r_e    |            2 | relationship_id |      179429 |      |
|          1 | t_r_e    |            3 | entity_id       |      179429 |      |
|          1 | t_e_r    |            1 | type            |           6 | YES  |
|          1 | t_e_r    |            2 | entity_id       |      179429 |      |
|          1 | t_e_r    |            3 | relationship_id |      179429 |      |
+------------+----------+--------------+-----------------+-------------+------+
```

And then the query I'm trying is:

```
INSERT INTO entity_relationship  
SELECT lt.entity_id entity_id, 
       py.relationship_id relationship_id,
       'implied-constituent' `type` 
FROM entity_relationship lt,
     entity_relationship ly,
     entity_relationship pt,
     entity_relationship py
WHERE lt.type='constituent'
  AND lt.relationship_id = ly.relationship_id
  AND ly.type='constituency'
  AND ly.entity_id = pt.entity_id 
  AND pt.type='constituent' 
  AND pt.relationship_id = py.relationship_id 
  AND py.type='constituency';
```

The problem is this is taking 42s to run (even when the query results in zero rows to insert). The output of EXPLAIN (on the SELECT) shows:

```
+--------+-----+----+-------+---+------------------------+-----+------------------------+
| s._type|table|type|key    |len|ref                     |rows |Extra                   |
+--------+-----+----+-------+---+------------------------+-----+------------------------+
| SIMPLE |lt   |ref |t_r_e  |2  |const                   |89714|Using where; Using index|
| SIMPLE |ly   |ref |r_t_e  |6  |lt.relationship_id,const|    1|Using where; Using index|
| SIMPLE |pt   |ref |PRIMARY|4  |ly.entity_id            |    1|Using where             |
| SIMPLE |py   |ref |r_t_e  |6  |pt.relationship_id,const|    1|Using where; Using index|
+--------+-----+----+-------+---+------------------------+-----+------------------------+
```

Which looks OK - except perhaps the 3rd line where it does not say Using Index.

Can anyone see a way to optimise this?

Comment: My guess is that you are trying to implement something like Closure Table (which is a model for hierarchical data). See this slideshow: [Models for hierarchical data](http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/models-for-hierarchical-data)

Comment: Thanks for sharing. Yeah, sort of but it's not limited parent-child  implementations. But the question is about optimisation not how-to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### How to fix it in MySQL

As can be seen from line 3 of the EXPLAIN statement, a [edit:]*covering* index is not being used here. It needs to join on the entity_id and the type and no key is available for that.

```
ALTER TABLE entity_relationship ADD KEY e_t_r 
   (entity_id, type, relationship_id);
```

This makes the key available, but MySQL chooses not to use it. It can be forced with: `USE INDEX (e_t_r)` :

```
SELECT lt.entity_id entity_id, 
       py.relationship_id relationship_id,
       'implied-constituent' `type` 
FROM entity_relationship lt,
     entity_relationship ly,
     entity_relationship pt USE INDEX (e_t_r),
     entity_relationship py
WHERE lt.type='constituent'
  AND lt.relationship_id = ly.relationship_id
  AND ly.type='constituency'
  AND ly.entity_id = pt.entity_id 
  AND pt.type='constituent' 
  AND pt.relationship_id = py.relationship_id 
  AND py.type='constituency';
```

**This now runs in 0.8s.** (compare to 17.7s without forcing it to use that index.) This is with MySQL 5.1.63.

### How to fix it in MariaDb

Well, you don't have to!

MariaDb executes the query very fast with or without the `USE INDEX` intervention (0.25s, but it's on a different host so I would expect this to be nearer the 0.8s in the optimised version above).

Also, MariaDb does not use the new index and is quite happy with the t_e_r index, including using it as a covering index (i.e. uses the index for the entire data fetch).

I'm getting more and more impressed with MariaDb and now considering switching.

Comment: `Using index` in `Extra` does not mean what you think it means.  The index used for a join is found in the `Key` column.  That value is `NULL` when you are not using an index (your first query was using the primary key for the join).  When you see `Using index`, that means your query is exploiting that index as a covering index and avoiding the need to retrieve rows from the table.  You didn't technically optimize your join, you only made it so the server has to read less data to return the results. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/explain-output.html#jointype_index

Comment: Thanks, I've edited first line to be clearer. But the question was about optimising the query, not just the join. And I achieved that by 20x, which is good! I'm interested with what you say to try it with a non-covering index (and to try MariaDb without that index), but I suspect the table lookup is what was causing it grief. Will report back if I do these test. Thanks for your help.